# Problem whit time exception java time limit exceeded

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have to resolve a problem , The function "Thor" Receives 3 Array List and an int, the algorithm must be uploaded to a page that corroborates if the function is correct, in the first tests the page returns what expected, but when continue testing, returns "time limit exceeded, code used too much CPU". I need help solving this, thank you!

```
import java.util.*;

public class microondas {
    public static long thor(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> f, ArrayList<Integer> p, int D) {
        long acumu,peso,altura,fuerza,distancia;
        acumu=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++) {
                for(int s=0;s<p.size();s++) {
                    peso=p.get(s);
                    altura=a.get(i);
                    fuerza=f.get(i);
                    distancia=(altura*fuerza)/peso;
                    if(distancia>=D) {
                    acumu+=1;   
                }
            }
        }
        return acumu;
    }
}
```

How i can save memory? I think that the 2D bucle its the problem.

Comment: [Check this out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/) and try to post big O questions only if you do your homework first :)

Comment: Well im doing my "homework" but I got stuck in a part and I wanted to ask the community, I don’t see the grace of responding with that double meaning

Answer (score 0):

In this code and with available information only basic micro-optimization is possible: there's no need to calculate `altura` / `fuerza` in the nested loop because these variables depend on first loop.
Also, division by the constant value may be moved outside the nested loop:

```
a.get(i) * f.get(i) / f.get(s) >= D is the same as a.get(i) * f.get(i) / D >= f.get(s)
```

```java
public static long thor(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> f, ArrayList<Integer> p, int D) {
    long acumu = 0;
    int iters = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = a.size(); i < n; i++) {
        long product = a.get(i) * f.get(i) / D;

        for (int peso : p) {
            if (product >= peso) {
                acumu++;
            }
            iters++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("thor iterations: " + iters);

    return acumu;
}
```

However, it is unlikely to help resolve a TLE because this code anyway has complexity `O(N * M)` where `N` is the size of `a`/`f` and `M` is the size of `p`.

Further optimization could be:

- pre-calculate and sort the list of products,
- sort list `p`
- when iterating list `p` remember the index of the last valid `peso` to discard the tail containing small values.
- some shortcuts are possible:

  - if the largest product is less than the minimal `peso`, all products may be discarded and 0 is returned;
  - if the largest `peso` is less or equal to the minimal product, the result is `product.size() * p.size()`

```java
public static long thorFaster(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> f, List<Integer> p, int D) {
    Collections.sort(p);
    List<Integer> products = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0, n = a.size(); i < n; i++) {
        products.add(a.get(i) * f.get(i) / D);
    }
    Collections.sort(products, Collections.reverseOrder());
    if (products.get(0) < p.get(0)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (p.get(p.size() - 1) <= products.get(products.size() - 1)) {
        return p.size() * products.size();
    }

    long acumu = 0;
    int iters = 0;

    int lastP = p.size();
    for (int i = 0, n = products.size(); i < n; i++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < lastP; s++) {
            iters++;

            int peso = p.get(s);
            if (peso <= products.get(i)) {
                acumu++;
            } else {
                lastP = s; // found limit
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("thorFaster iterations: " + iters);

    return acumu;
}
```

Tests:

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8);
List<Integer> f = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 0);
List<Integer> p = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5, 8, 10);

System.out.println("thor: " + thor(a, f, p, 2));
System.out.println("thorFaster: " + thorFaster(a, f, p, 2));
```

Output:

```
thor iterations: 35
thor: 10
thorFaster iterations: 13
thorFaster: 10
```